# How to preview file recieved as a application/octet-stream using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I'm using a `Java` `Servlet` to pass a file as a input stream to the client side. so when I get the input stream in the client side I want to preview it in a web page using `javascript`. I found some ways to save files in [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side) and [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2012/01/how-to-download-data-as-a-file-from-javascript.html) but could not find a way to preview it without saving. so hope someone can help me.. :)

**Servlet**

```
InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("File", filePath[filePath.length - 1]);
ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
while ((read = in.read(bufferData)) != -1) {
    os.write(bufferData, 0, read);
}
os.flush();
os.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: You need to define what 'preview' means. Say it is an Excel file, how would you 'preview' that? Or are you only working with images here?

Comment: @Gimby I'm  currently only working with images. most of the time it will be images and .txt files. can you help me with this. by preview I meant showing file content in browser.

Comment: No I can't help. Don't use application/octet-stream, use the proper content-type so the browser can do it for you.

Comment: you mean at the server side right.? I have to find the correct mime type and return it to the client. ok I'll try that.